# Vispy: Implementing a time slider for playback control of a visualization embedded in QT GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, vispy

I have been having a quick play around with embedding my Vispy code into a Qt-based visualization, based on the example code in the Vispy gallery by @djhoese. I have it working using timer events in a background thread to run the data generation. My main goal now is to implement some playback controls for the visualization, ideally using a `QTSlider` or something along those lines, with some play/pause buttons.

I am at a bit of a hurdle in how to achieve this, primarily the issue is how to control the Vispy visualization using the slider and how the background thread generating the data will tie in properly.

I have made a very minimal working reproduction of some of my code, it encapsulates most of what I am doing in my main code.

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

from vispy import scene
from vispy.app import use_app

CANVAS_SIZE = (800, 600)  # (width, height)
TUBE_COLOR_CHOICES = ["green", "red", "blue"]


class Controls(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tube_color_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Object Colours:")
        layout.addWidget(self.tube_color_label)
        self.tube_color_chooser = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.tube_color_chooser.addItems(TUBE_COLOR_CHOICES)
        layout.addWidget(self.tube_color_chooser)

        layout.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class CanvasWrapper:
    def __init__(self, visualization_dict):

        self.canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys="interactive", size=CANVAS_SIZE, bgcolor="black")
        self.view = self.canvas.central_widget.add_view()
        self.objects = {}

        for _, object in enumerate(visualization_dict["objects"]):

            object_parameters = visualization_dict["objects"][object]
            object_type = object_parameters["type"]

            if object_type == "rod":

                is_closed = object_parameters["closed"]
                color = TUBE_COLOR_CHOICES[0]

                object_position = object_parameters["position"][0].transpose()[:-1]
                object_radius = object_parameters["radius"][0]

                # Calculates tube meshdata
                initial_tube_meshdata = scene.visuals.Tube(
                    points=object_position,
                    radius=object_radius,
                    closed=is_closed,
                    color=color,
                )._meshdata

                self.objects[f"{object}"] = scene.visuals.Tube(
                    points=[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
                    parent=self.view.scene,
                    name=f"{object}",
                )
                self.objects[f"{object}"].set_data(meshdata=initial_tube_meshdata)

        time_data = visualization_dict["time"]
        self.time_text = scene.Text(
            f"Time: {time_data[234]:.4f}",
            bold=True,
            font_size=14,
            color="w",
            pos=(80, 30),
            parent=self.canvas.central_widget,
        )

        self.view.camera = scene.TurntableCamera(elevation=0, azimuth=0)
        self.view.camera.set_range(
            x=(-0.1, 0.1),
            y=(0, 0),
            z=(0, 1),
        )


    def set_tube_color(self, color):
        # In this minimal code example set_tube_colour 
        # wont work as it gets overwritten by meshdata
        print(f"Changing tube color")
        for object in self.objects:
            self.objects[object].set_data(color=color)

    def update_data(self, new_data_dict):
        for object in self.objects:
            self.objects[object].set_data(meshdata=new_data_dict[object])
        self.time_text.text = f"Time: {new_data_dict['time']:.4f}"

    def add_axis(
        self, axis_direction, domain=None, color="white", font_size=10, axis_width=2
    ):
        # ... 
        min_val, max_val = domain[0], domain[1]

        if min_val == max_val:
            return

        if axis_direction == "x":

            axis = scene.Axis(
                pos=[[min_val, 0], [max_val, 0]],
                domain=domain,
                tick_direction=(0, -1),
                parent=self.view.scene,
            )

        elif axis_direction == "z":

            axis = scene.Axis(
                pos=[[0, min_val], [0, max_val]],
                domain=domain,
                tick_direction=(-1, 0),
                parent=self.view.scene,
            )

            rot_mat = np.array(
                [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
            )
            axis.transform = scene.transforms.MatrixTransform(matrix=rot_mat)
        # ...

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closing = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, canvas_wrapper: CanvasWrapper, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self._controls = Controls()
        main_layout.addWidget(self._controls)
        self._canvas_wrapper = canvas_wrapper
        main_layout.addWidget(self._canvas_wrapper.canvas.native)

        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self._connect_controls()

    def _connect_controls(self):
        self._controls.tube_color_chooser.currentTextChanged.connect(
            self._canvas_wrapper.set_tube_color
        )

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Closing main window!")
        self.closing.emit()
        return super().closeEvent(event)


class DataSource(QtCore.QObject):

    new_data = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, visualization_dict, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._should_end = False
        self._num_iters = len(visualization_dict["time"])
        self.visualization_dict = visualization_dict

    def run_data_creation(self):
        print("Run data creation is starting")
        for i in range(self._num_iters):
            if self._should_end:
                break

            data_dict = {}

            for num, object in enumerate(self.visualization_dict["objects"]):

                object_parameters = self.visualization_dict["objects"][object]
                object_type = object_parameters["type"]

                if object_type == "rod":

                    is_closed = object_parameters["closed"]
                    color = object_parameters["color"]

                    object_position = object_parameters["position"][i].transpose()[:-1]
                    object_radius = object_parameters["radius"][i]

                    tube_meshdata = scene.visuals.Tube(
                        points=object_position,
                        radius=object_radius,
                        closed=is_closed,
                    )._meshdata

                    data_dict[f"{object}"] = tube_meshdata

            data_dict["time"] = visualization_dict["time"][i]    
            self.new_data.emit(data_dict)

        self.finished.emit()

    def stop_data(self):
        self._should_end = True


if __name__ == "__main__":

    time_arr = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
    object_x = np.array(
        [0.1 * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 80) + 16 * t / np.pi) for t in time_arr]
    )
    object_z = np.array(
        [np.linspace(0, 0.3, 80) + z_shift for z_shift in np.linspace(0, 0.95, 1000)]
    )
    object_y = np.zeros(shape=(1000, 80))

    object_coords = np.stack(arrays=[object_x, object_y, object_z], axis=1)
    object_radius = np.full((1000, 79), 0.00385)

    visualization_dict = {
        "objects": {
            "shearable_rod": {
                "type": "rod",
                "position": object_coords,
                "radius": object_radius,
                "color": "purple",
                "closed": False,
            }
        },
        "time": time_arr
    }

    app = use_app("pyqt5")
    app.create()

    canvas_wrapper = CanvasWrapper(visualization_dict)
    canvas_wrapper.add_axis("z", domain=[0, 1])
    canvas_wrapper.add_axis("x", domain=[-0.2, 0.2])

    win = MyMainWindow(canvas_wrapper)
    data_thread = QtCore.QThread(parent=win)
    data_source = DataSource(visualization_dict)
    data_source.moveToThread(data_thread)

    # update the visualization when there is new data
    data_source.new_data.connect(canvas_wrapper.update_data)
    # start data generation when the thread is started
    data_thread.started.connect(data_source.run_data_creation)
    # if the data source finishes before the window is closed, kill the thread
    data_source.finished.connect(data_thread.quit, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)
    # if the window is closed, tell the data source to stop
    win.closing.connect(data_source.stop_data, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)
    # when the thread has ended, delete the data source from memory
    data_thread.finished.connect(data_source.deleteLater)

    win.show()
    data_thread.start()
    app.run()

    data_thread.wait(5000)
```

An ideal solution would be that the background thread continues to generate the data and the slider will continuously update to allow scrubbing through the available time range which has data generated for it. The data from the background thread can be easily stored in a variable in the `CanvasWrapper` for example (or QT may have some sort of buffer that the thread can save the data to) but I don't know if that is the ideal way of doing so. But then the issue for me is how to then use the slider to control the vispy canvas.

Alternatively, I can pre-calculate the data before visualization if that makes it more achievable which can negate the need for a separate thread, however, ideally having it calculated at the same time in a background process would be better for the user experience.

Just as a side note, the data generation process in the example is creating tube mesh instances from my given data and using the metadata from that to update the canvas visuals. In my full code, I've got some functions to calculate the vertices of a tube mesh to then use to update the canvas visuals, instead of having to create an entire new instance of a `Tube` just to get the meshdata, and will prevent the color for example from being overwritten during updating the visual using the meshdata, so the QTWidgets will work.

And any other recommendations on Vispy/QT best practices within the rest of the code are also of course welcome, particularly on the visualization speed. Even when pre-computing the meshdatas and no data generation thread, the visualization for this very basic example updates at around 25fps. I am not sure if it is just down to my very old computer, but given that the intention is to use this visualization tool for simulations that may have dozens of tubes/rods it is a definite concern.

Apologies for the length post and any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the first question to answer is what you want the user experience to be like? Are you going to have an ever-growing slider that gets more and more possible "ticks" as new data comes in? Or are you only going to save the last N entries? Bottom line, how big is `self.objects` going to be? Otherwise, I think your `set_data` will need to update the slider and "cache" the data if needed. The slider can then be connected to a method to display the correct Visual(s). For performance, you may have to balance the number of overall Visuals and reusing the same set of Visuals.

Comment: You could have a couple "cache" Visuals representing the next time step, the previous time step, and the current time step, but you set `.parent = None` for the Visuals not being currently shown but still set the data on them. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the needs of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the response @djhoese. Having an ever growing slider would be ideal, but I’m still a bit unsure how to implement the slider in QT that can be used to control the visualisation. Not sure if you have any code you could point me to that does that or know how to adapt my code to do so. Thanks

Comment: I don't have code for that, sorry. I'm not sure I understand the difficulty though. Create a slider, connect the signal that it uses when the slider value changes to a method, in that method call `.set_data` on the visuals that need to be updated. Your wrapper class will likely require a list or dictionary of the data to be shown for each of the ticks in the slider. For the ever-growing slider, I'm not sure how that would "feel" from a users point of view, but I also don't have any better suggestions at the moment.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misunderstood what you suggested but I have got it working (maybe a bit suboptimally) with the functionality I was looking for. Thank you for your invaluable help once again @djhoese .